# Does grease pencil lineart have a material based line color option?

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

Freestyle line art has a line color option for multiple materials assigned to one object.
Does grease pencil line art have an equivalent option?

Separating the object according to material and assigning grease pencil line art to each individual material is a workaround I have thought of, but that causes more problems than it solves.

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image: Freestyle colors]

[image: Grease pencil monochrome]

[image: Material line color option]